# Is it dangerous to have a very long request_queue_size in Python.SocketServer.TCPServer?

Tags: python

I'm going to run a small server inheriting from `Python.SocketServer.TCPServer`. In case the code is too slow, I could make it threaded or just expand the queue size, and it will take a bit longer to run. Are there any dangers in setting the request_queue_size to a large value (say a few thousands)?
The only very important thing in my programme is that I don't lose any data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your OS, the maximum value for `request_queue_size` will be 128 (that's the *default* maximum size on Linux and Mac OS X, at least). Higher values won't give an error but will just silently be limited.

Higher values won't necessarily be a problem I think, although I would seriously consider using some form of threading (or, if appropriate, an asynchronous solution using `gevent` or something similar). The `SocketServer` module provides mixins for creating threaded or forking socket servers.